# Heartbeat effect

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create a simple heart beat animation i.e. object scale starts from x1 goes up to x5 comes down to x3 goes back up to x5 and then back to x1 waits for T secs and then loop the animation.

Currently I am using a lazy implementation which lerps to x5 and checks if it has reached the target size and lerps to x3 and so on (yes it has a lot of if statements).

What I am looking for is an elegant way to make this animation (may be a mathematical equation) which does not uses so many if checks.

Comment: Why are you not using Unity's animation system that is integrated in the editor? It would seem to be good enough for your requirement

Comment: Unity animation does not provides much control. Every time you need to make the changes you will have to update the animation. in case to script you only need to change a few variables. which can also be easily tweaked at runtime.

Comment: Post what you currently have. That will tell us how to improve your code.

Comment: I agree with @enduser, having an animator controller to animate between a healthy heart or a dying heart or any heart animation would, in my opinion be easier than changing it in script since you can visualize without having to run the whole game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely use unity animation.

Add some key frames to change the scale of the object.

Further modify the curve of animation in `Curves` tab (default is `Dopesheet` tab). You can find this on the down left side of the animation panel.

Edit scale.x,y,z so that it looks something like this:

[image]